# Check for plugged in network cable on startup

Tags: networking, networkmanager, ethernet

I actually wanted to post the below as an answer to this question titled: [ifup eth0 timeout during boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132616/ifup-eth0-timeout-during-boot). But am not sure if this is right approach or it's a way of screwing up things badly.

We can actually check if the network cable is connected to the machine, or not, by running the command,

```
grep "" /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier
```

When the network cable is plugged in, the output would be **1** for the above command and when it is not plugged in, the output would be **0** for the above command. I tested the above part in my system and it worked fine as expected.

Now the question lies in how to include this condition on **startup**. We can include this in the network **startup** file, which can check this condition before bringing up the interfaces. In RHEL box the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` is used to bring up the network interfaces.

So, If I change the file to look like,

```
cable=$(grep "" /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier)
if $cable -eq 1 then
   #rest of the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 as it is. 
else
   break
```

However, before proposing this method, or even trying on my machine, my question is: When the services are being brought up will the `/sys/class/net/eth0/carrier` be ready and available? Assuming this approach works, if I decide to use wireless network will there be a problem?

Comment: Seems related: [Check whether network cable is plugged in without bringing interface up](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26962/check-whether-network-cable-is-plugged-in-without-bringing-interface-up)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the interface has to be up for the above suggested method to work. I made the changes in my file as I suggested in the question and ended up receiving the error as "**Invalid argument**". So, I believe the interface should be up to query if the wired connection is available or not. I also found more useful information for this answer: [How to detect the physical connected state of a network cable/connector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808560/how-to-detect-the-physical-connected-state-of-a-network-cable-connector).

> `cat /sys/class/net/ethX` is by far the easiest method.
>
> The interface has to be up though, else you will get an invalid
>   argument error.
>
> So first:
>
> ```
> ifconfig ethX up
> ```
>
> Then:
>
> ```
> cat /sys/class/net/ethX
> ```